# doing something different to one item in an array if condition is met (php)

Tags: php

I'm grabbing rows from a query and spitting them out but I'd like to treat one of the items differently if it matches a variable I've set.

```
$systemID = foo;
$systems = mysqli_query($conxn,"SELECT * FROM system ORDER BY system_name");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($systems)) {
    echo $row['system_id'];
    echo $row['system_name'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

What I'd like to have happen is if `$row['system_id'] == $systemID`, `echo` a different statement and then return to completing the rest of the array.

Comment: so why don't you put that if statement inside the loop?

Comment: that was my initial thought...I tried but kept getting syntax errors. I thought it would look something like:

if ($row['system_id'] == $systemID) { echo "this"; } else { echo "rest of array"; }

but that didn't work.

Comment: post the code, then..

Comment: hahah, I got it! thanks for making me think it out. I was complicating matters initially with an else statement. :)

Comment: actually, that didn't work fully. getting a duplicate printing of the affected result.

Comment: You haven't posted your code so it's a bit difficult for use to see what's not right about it.